# Ansible playbook, set environment variables not working

Tags: python, ansible

I have to install psycopg to an old python (2.4). Everything works fine, except setting the environment variables -> LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
- name: install psycopg
  shell: "{{ item }}"
    environment:
      CPPFLAGS: "-I/my_python/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mx/DateTime/mxDateTime"
      LD_LIBRARY_PATH: "/path_to_postgresql/lib"
  args:
    chdir: "/path_to_psycopg_src/"
  with_items:
    - ./configure --prefix=/my_python --with-python=/my_python/bin/python --with-postgres-libraries=/path_to_postgresql/lib --with-postgres-includes=/path_postgresql/include --with-mxdatetime-includes=/my_python/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mx/DateTime/mxDateTime
    - make
    - make install
```

After successfull installation I get the following error:

```
>>> import psycopg
    ImportError: libpq.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I export it manually, it works fine:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path_postgresql/lib"
>>> import psycopg
>>> psycopg
<module 'psycopg' from '/my_python/lib/python2.4/site-packages/psycopgmodule.so'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` just for `install psycopg` task. If you want to set an environment variable not just for task/playbook I think you need to edit `/etc/environment`

Comment: So it is not possible in an ansible playbook?

Comment: You can edit /etc/environment in your ansible playbook

Comment: My problem is, that I have no rights to edit /etc/environment

Comment: So maybe you can edit .bashrc for specific user http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session

Comment: Ok. Thx. I will modify my bash_rc. So the 'environment' setting in the playbook is totally useless?

Comment: No, is very useful, but it works only for task | playbook and sometimes you need to set some envs to run them properly